# How to speed up eager loading of foreign collections?

Tags: java, performance, sqlite, ormlite, foreign-collection

I have a database table mapped with ORMlite, it contains some data (18 columns) and it also contains `ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)`.

Problem is when loading all data from this table ... ORMlite is creating query for every item instead using joins. Which is resulting in 67124 queries and taking forever to load all objects from this table.

This could be however done in right join query under few seconds? Why to generate thousands of queries instead?

How can I speed it up? Do I have to write raw query and then RawRowMapper , which makes using ORM pointless..

How to deal with loading eager collections in ormlite? Because `queryForAll` is not way..

Comment: Why are you trying to load all data and how? ORMs aren't meant for reporting or ETL, which are the only valid reasons to "load all data". Use a stored procedure or view for this. What you describe is the `N+1` problem, which should be fixed by using eager loading. How are you making the query and how did you define mappings?

Comment: PS ORMs *really,really* aren't meant for reporting or ETL. This is just an academic discussion. You gain nothing by converting rows and values to objects when you *don't* intend to apply any domain logic to them.

Comment: In this case I need to load all data, which will be later all displayed in 3D graph and used for simulation... There is big domain logic behind this. This table has much more columns and whole database has much more tables.. but this time I need to load all and its slow..Anyway even if there wont be big domain logic and you load all data at start, database is still good way to save this data as its columns can be updated on runtime , instead of rewritting whole xml file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem is when loading all data from this table ... ORMlite is creating query for every item instead using joins. Which is resulting in 67124 queries and taking forever to load all objects from this table.

It's ORM_Lite_ for a reason.  Lot of people have asked for the join support on foreign collections but I've not gotten to it yet.  It's not easy.

If you still want to use ORMLite then I'd recommend *not* using `eager = true` and doing 2 queries instead.  One query for your main item and then another query using the DAO associated with the collection entity using `IN`.  Something like:

```
qb = accountDao.queryBuilder();
qb.where()...;
List<Account> accounts = qb.query();

// build a list of account-ids
List<Long> accountIds = new ArrayList<>();
for (Account account : accounts) {
    accountIds.add(account.getId());
}

// now use this list of ids to get your other entities
List<Order> orders = orderDao.queryBuilder().where().in("accountId", accountIds).query();
// now you have a list of orders for all of your ids
// you will need to associate each order with its account
```

Hope this helps.